# display result with latest date based on searched userid

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone know how to retrieve data from database using MySQL based on user id and the latest date the user visit? When search the `userid` value, supposedly it display the details on latest `vdate` with the same searched `userid`. But when I execute this SQL query, it display all the user with the latest `vdate` if the searched `userid` exist on that day. If only one `userid` exist on that date, it display correctly based on search value. But if there are multiple user exist on that date, it will display all the user.

Result for now:

Table `register`:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| userid    | vdate         | country   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| 3         | 04/09/2021    | indonesia |
| 1         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
| 2         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
| 3         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Searched user id: 3

Displayed:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| userid    | vdate         | country   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| 1         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
| 2         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
| 3         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

The result that i want to display:

```
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| userid    | vdate         | country   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| 3         | 05/09/2021    | indonesia |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

It will display based on the last vdate the user register. If the last vdate the user register is on 04/09/2021, then it should display the result on vdate 04/09/2021 and not the current date. This is the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM register 
WHERE vdate IN (SELECT MAX(vdate) FROM register WHERE userid = '$search')
```

Comment: What's the "vdate" field type? Setting the "vdate" field type as "date" would allow you to use dedicated date functions in SQL.

Comment: the "vdate" field type i set it as date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the outer query by the user id as well.  I might suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM register r
WHERE r.userid = ? AND
      r.vdate = (SELECT MAX(r2.vdate) FROM register r2 WHERE r2.userid = r.userid);
```

Note the use of the `?`, which is a *parameter placeholder*.  Do not munge query strings with values.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: it works now. thank you. do you mind to explain why it is not okay to munge query strings with values ?

Comment: @RonaY . . . It opens the code to SQL injection attacks.  And perhaps more importantly, it makes the code subject to run-time errors that are really hard to test for and prevent.